# Capitalize first letter of my acronyms description list

Tags: acronyms

I need caps on the first letter of all my acronyms description list (package acronyms, not glossaries). Following the tips on the forums I could not solve my problem. There are problems regarding the concomitant use of `\Acf`, `\textit{}` inside acronym description and `\acroextra{}`.

How could I change this piece of code to have token #3 changed before the following effects of this and other macros?

```
\newcommand*\AC@acro[1]{%
  \@ifnextchar[{\AC@@acro{#1}}{\AC@@acro{#1}[#1]}}
\newcommand\AC@@acro{}
\def\AC@@acro#1[#2]#3{%
  \ifAC@nolist%
  \else%
  \ifAC@printonlyused%
    \expandafter\ifx\csname acused@#1\endcsname\AC@used%
       \item[\protect\AC@hypertarget{#1}{\aclabelfont{#2}}] #3%
          \ifAC@withpage%
            \expandafter\ifx\csname r@acro:#1\endcsname\relax%
               \PackageInfo{acronym}{%
                 Acronym #1 used in text but not spelled out in
                 full in text}%
            \else%
               \dotfill\pageref{acro:#1}%
            \fi%
          \fi\\%
    \fi%
 \else%
    \item[\protect\AC@hypertarget{#1}{\aclabelfont{#2}}] #3%
 \fi%
 \fi%
```

Comment: Welcome to SE. *Always* provide a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that). There are too many things that can vary depending on which packages you're using.

Comment: Texmaker 5.0.3
(compiled with Qt 5.12.8)
Copyright (c) 2003-2018 by Pascal Brachet

Acronym package version 1.42 (2019-11-11)

Comment: That's not a Minimal Working Example. Please provide *compilable* code. In particular, your choice of editor is irrelevant.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick answers. I cant pick part of my thesis right now. It is faster to replace by a PDF page. I thought the answer was simple like in any other language.

Comment: LaTeX is a programming language just like any other language: you can't expect to debug a code blind without even the knowledge of which libraries you're using. LaTeX happens to be *very* customizable, so context is crucial.

Comment: Ok.. thank you... I risk to transfer to Overleaf and I discovered the problem right now but not the solution... It is failing on accentuations. The first letter cant be "á" (for example).  But every other words are ok. It is some macros' conflict.

Comment: Overleaf is a good tool, just remember one caveat: it tries to ignore errors and forces compilation even with bad syntax. It makes errors harder to find, and can lead to nasty surprises when you share the code with people using other tools.